# composer install:Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: laravel, composer-php, homestead

I tried to install  homestead command line with the command: `composer global require "laravel/homestead=~2.0"`

```
Problem 1
    - The requested package laravel/installer == 1.3.1.0 could not be found.
    Problem 2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.2.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.2.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.1.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.1.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.1.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.1.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.1.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.1.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.1.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.1.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.1.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.0.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.0.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.0.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.0.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.0.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.0.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.0.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.0.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.0.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.0.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.0.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.0.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.0.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.0.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.0.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/homestead v2.0.1
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/process v3.0.2
    - Installation request for laravel/homestead ~2.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/homestead[v2.0.0, v2.0.1, v2.0.10, v2.0.11, v2.0.12, v2.0.13, v2.0.14, v2.0.15, v2.0.16, v2.0.17, v2.0.2, v2.0.3, v2.0.4, v2.0.5, v2.0.6, v2.0.7, v2.0.8, v2.0.9, v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.2.0, v2.2.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/process v3.0.2
    - laravel/homestead v2.0.0 requires symfony/process ~2.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, v2.0.10, v2.0.12, v2.0.13, v2.0.14, v2.0.15, v2.0.16, v2.0.17, v2.0.18, v2.0.19, v2.0.20, v2.0.21, v2.0.22, v2.0.23, v2.0.24, v2.0.25, v2.0.9, v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.36, v2.3.37, v2.3.38, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.13, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.2, v2.8.3].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.0, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.1, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.10, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.11, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.12, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.13, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.14, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.15, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.16, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.17, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.18, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.19, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.2, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.20, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.21, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.22, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.23, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.24, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.25, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.26, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.27, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.28, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.29, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.3, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.30, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.31, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.32, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.33, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.34, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.35, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.36, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.37, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.38, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.4, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.5, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.6, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.7, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.8, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.3.9, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.4.0, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.4.1, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.4.10, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.4.2, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.4.3, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.4.4, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.4.5, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.4.6, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.4.7, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.4.8, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.4.9, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.5.0, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.5.1, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.5.10, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.5.11, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.5.12, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.5.2, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.5.3, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.5.4, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.5.5, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.5.6, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.5.7, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.5.8, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.5.9, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.6.0, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.6.1, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.6.10, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.6.11, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.6.12, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.6.13, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.6.2, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.6.3, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.6.4, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.6.5, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.6.6, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.6.7, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.6.8, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.6.9, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.7.0, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.7.1, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.7.10, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.7.2, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.7.3, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.7.4, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.7.5, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.7.6, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.7.7, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.7.8, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.7.9, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.8.0, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.8.1, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.8.2, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.8.3, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[2.0.4, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[2.0.5, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[2.0.6, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[2.0.7, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.0.10, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.0.12, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.0.13, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.0.14, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.0.15, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.0.16, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.0.17, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.0.18, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.0.19, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.0.20, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.0.21, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.0.22, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.0.23, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.0.24, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.0.25, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.0.9, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.1.0, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.1.1, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.1.10, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.1.11, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.1.12, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.1.13, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.1.2, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.1.3, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.1.4, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.1.5, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.1.6, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.1.7, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.1.8, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.1.9, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.2.0, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.2.1, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.2.10, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.2.11, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.2.2, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.2.3, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.2.4, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.2.5, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.2.6, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.2.7, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.2.8, v3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/process[v2.2.9, v3.0.2].
    - Installation request for symfony/process == 3.0.2.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/process[v3.0.2].
```

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more details.

Read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for further common problems.

Comment: Do you have a question? Please state what you did, e.g. which command you executed, and what you expected. Currently you only dumped a huge error output into a textarea, which is not helpful.

Comment: When I execute this command  "composer global require "laravel/homestead=~2.0" ",above error exists in the terminal

Comment: You should be able to edit your question and add any relevant information to it.

Comment: A quick google search reveals that Homestead 2.0 probably has compatibility issues, which might be resolved in 3.0. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34518766/cannot-install-global-homestead-your-requirements-could-not-be-resolved

Comment: @zyMacro post an answer explaining how you solved the issue below

Comment: I intentionally posted this as a comment because I consider this question not to be worth being kept for eternity. It is heavily downvoted and badly written, omitting any necessary information for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with the command below

```
composer global require "laravel/homestead=~3.0"
```